# Declaring empty C++ array with aggregate initializer

Tags: c++, arrays

In C++, unlike in C, an empty array `T name[]` is illegal,

> the type declared is "array of unknown bound of T", which is a kind of incomplete type.

However, it is legal when

> used in a declaration with an aggregate initializer

like `T name[] = {val1, val2, ...}`, where the array is allocated with the number of elements in the initializer list.

What is the expected behaviour when the aggregate initializer is empty? `T name[] = {}`

I have tested g++ (version 4.8.4) and clang (version 3.4), neither of which give any error or warning, and seem to allocate 1 element. Is this the defined behaviour? Documentation?

```
int a[] = {};
int b[] = {};
```

Results in:

```
a[0] -> 0x7ffc3de28dd8
a[1] -> 0x7ffc3de28ddc
b[0] -> 0x7ffc3de28ddc
b[1] -> 0x7ffc3de28de0
```

Comment: What versions of gcc and clang? gcc 6.1 and clang 3.8 complain about the array of length 0.

Comment: gcc 4.8.4, clang 3.4

Comment: The addresses of the arrays still have to be valid, so that's probably why something is allocated. But I think dereferencing is undefined behavior when the size of the array is 0. You can get the size of an array literal with: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the working draft, [[8.5.1/5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5) (*Aggregates*):

> An empty initializer list {} shall not be used as the initializer-clause for an array of unknown bound.

See also [[footnote/105]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#footnote-105):

> The syntax provides for empty initializer-lists, but nonetheless C++ does not have zero length arrays.

It sounds like an UB.

---

Note also that this compiles as expected:

```
template<int N>
void f(int(&)[N]) { }

int main() {
    int v[] = {42};
    f(v);
}
```

But it doesn't work anymore if you use:

```
int v[] = {};
```

Tested with GCC.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ standard 1.8.6 (C++ 14):

> Two objects that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one
>   is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class
>   subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise,
>   they shall have distinct addresses.4

Compiler must allocate at least one element of your arrays to satisfy the above requirement.